# Dropdown menu on blogspot is not working

Tags: menu, blogger, dropdown, blogspot

I have a problem with the dropdown menu on my blogspot.
it is header widget with java/css script that i downloaded on internet
it works well on the homepage or on any post but not work on page of label.
I divide posts into the diffirent label and when on the page of a label. I can't click on dropdown menu. it shows the sub-menu but when the mouse move into them. they will disapear suddenly.

example:
here is the page of label that the dropdown menu not work
http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/C%20Language
on this page you cannot choose the sub-menu on the drop down menu.
plz tell me to fix.
Thanks

### [may thuy binh](http://tracdiaminhquan.com/may-thuy-binh-1.html)

```
<style type="text/css">@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,#cssmenu > ul{background:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-V2tGyRV9wIY/UjqTVGOrmXI/AAAAAAAABdQ/XYS2v7U8DUI/s1600/highlight-bg.png) repeat;padding-bottom:3px;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-weight:600}#cssmenu:before,#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:before,#cssmenu > ul:after{content:'';display:table}#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:after{clear:both}#cssmenu{width:auto;zoom:1}#cssmenu > ul{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fPLR6IIW7dU/UjqTVZksJTI/AAAAAAAABdU/EadZ1JqTCX8/s1600/menu-bg.png) repeat;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative}#cssmenu > ul li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}#cssmenu > ul > li{float:left;position:relative}#cssmenu > ul > li > a{padding:23px 26px;display:block;color:white;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #9e3825;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(116,37,2,0.7);line-height:18px}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-efkMXp2H1cU/UjqSzHrMVFI/AAAAAAAABdI/TbVQZkLhC4I/s1600/hover.png) repeat;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #97321f;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(122,42,26,0.64)}#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span{line-height:18px}#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hKJMJ6tutvA/UjqSigUJTSI/AAAAAAAABdA/EicRvUY_mlw/s1600/active.png) repeat}/* Childs */#cssmenu > ul ul{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:120px;background:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-V2tGyRV9wIY/UjqTVGOrmXI/AAAAAAAABdQ/XYS2v7U8DUI/s1600/highlight-bg.png) repeat;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:-1}#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul{opacity:1;visibility:visible;margin:0;color:#000;z-index:2;top:64px;left:0}#cssmenu > ul ul:before{content:'';position:absolute;top:-10px;width:100%;height:20px;background:transparent}#cssmenu > ul ul li{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%}#cssmenu > ul ul li a{padding:18px 26px;display:block;color:#393939;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;width:150px;border-left:4px solid transparent;-webkit-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;text-shadow:0 1px 0 white}#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover{border-left:4px solid #de553b;background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-efkMXp2H1cU/UjqSzHrMVFI/AAAAAAAABdI/TbVQZkLhC4I/s1600/hover.png) repeat;color:white;text-shadow:0 1px 0 black}#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fPLR6IIW7dU/UjqTVZksJTI/AAAAAAAABdU/EadZ1JqTCX8/s1600/menu-bg.png) repeat}</style><a href="http://24work.blogspot.com/" rel="dofollow" target="_blank" title="Drop Down Menus"><img src="https://bitly.com/24workpng1" alt="Drop Down Menus" border="0" style="position: fixed; bottom: 10%; right: 0%; top: 0px;" /></a><a href="http://24work.blogspot.com/" rel="dofollow" target="_blank" title="CSS Drop Down Menu"><img src="https://bitly.com/24workpng1" alt="CSS Drop Down Menu" border="0" style="position: fixed; bottom: 10%; right: 0%;" /></a><a href="http://24work.blogspot.com/" rel="dofollow" target="_blank" title="Pure CSS Dropdown Menu"><img src="https://bitly.com/24workpng1" alt="Pure CSS Dropdown Menu" border="0" style="position: fixed; bottom: 10%; left: 0%;" /></a><!-- Dont edit this CSS Drop Down Menu code or it will not work -->




<!-- customize your menus Links -->


<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Education%20-%20Teaching"><span>Education</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Python"><span>Python</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/C%20Language"><span>C/C++</span></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Medicine"><span>Medicine</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Make%20Money"><span>Make Money</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/YTube"><span>Youtube</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/SEO"><span>SEO</span></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Dropship"><span>Dropship</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Affiliate%20Marketing"><span>Affiliate Marketing</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Adwords"><span>Adwords</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Cryptocurrency"><span>Cryptocurrency</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Health"><span>Health</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Yoga"><span>Yoga</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Workout"><span>Workout</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Story"><span>Story</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.book4shares.com/search/label/Yoga"><span>Yoga</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```